# Hydrogen & Oxygen mentioned in Vedas and Itihasas?

Tags: scripture, vedas, science, itihasa

In the link given below I found some details about Ancient Batteries, Hydrogen & Oxygen discovered by Sage Agastya in India.

[**Ancient Batteries, Hydrogen & Oxygen discovered by Sage Agastya in India**](https://www.booksfact.com/vedas/ancient-batteries-hydrogen-oxygen-discovered-agastya.html)

I would like to know any evidence or mentions of Hydrogen & Oxygen in Vedas and Itihasas?

Along with Oxygen and Hydrogen any other chemical elements mentioned?

Comment: By etymology of Latin names derived from Sanskrit : Aurum - Svarna - Au - Gold. Argentinium - Arjuna - Ag - Silver

Comment: @ram, even for this site that is a credulity stretch...

Comment: @iruvar, maybe you want to look up [etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/argentine) before you opine

Comment: @ram, so you're saying argentine and arjun both mean white therefore the Latin Argentine must have been derived from the Sanskrit Arjuna? There are plenty of such Sanskrit and Latin cognate words - in fact one need look no further than the respective words for some of the numbers between one and ten. Linguistic science attributes the presence of these cognate words to Latin and Sanskrit having evolved from a single ancient proto-Indo-European ancient language. I don't think it's the case that Latin poached the words you mention from Sanskrit

Comment: @iruvar - "evolved from a single ancient proto-Indo-European ancient language" - which is.. ? Just saying PIE (proto-Indo-European) with no proof about its aksharas (alphabets), vyakarana (grammar), lipi (script) or kavya (literature) is hogwash. Sanskrit has all of these, along with written historical records going back to at least 5100 B.C, and much more if you count Itihasa/Puranas. Of course, these western indologists will hand wave these off as myth, because of their inability to accept the superiority of truth.

Comment: @ram - huh? I see where this conversation is veering, and no thanks, I'll stick to the science. Adios

Comment: @iruvar, " I'll stick to the science" - if you do, then we're on the same page.

Comment: @ram "Of course, these western indologists will hand wave these off as myth, because of their inability to accept the superiority of truth" are fairy tales superior?

Comment: The parts of the battery in the Samhita are a fraud. Tje original samhita never mentions anything about a battery.

Comment: @Wikash_ i didn't say anything about a battery. the etymology behind Aurum & Argentenium is indisputable.

Comment: @ram the part of the battery was not directed to you it was for the TS.

Comment: I wouldn't place much credence in the linked website. It references well-known pseudoscience in its eulogy of 'Egyptian science'. It's designed to snare the credulous, or the ignorant. More, it's also designed to appeal to those who feel intellectually insecure because they are made to feel that India is a failure simply because it did not discover European science first. This is just stupid, as Tagore pointed out. India already has plenty to get proud of already without pretending to spurious claims. Admittedly, European science, especially in its history is eurocentric, to the degree that it

Answer (score 1):

### I would like to know any evidence or mentions of Hydrogen & Oxygen in Vedas and Itihasas?

> **मित्रं हुवे पूतदक्षं  वरुणां च रिषाद्सम् 
>   धियं घृताचीं साधन्ता || ऋ०|१|२|७||**
>
> Let one who is desirous to form water by the combination of two substances take pure hydrogen gas highly heated, and, oxygen gas possessed of the property rusting, and let him combine them to form water.(rigved 1.2.7)

**Etymology of translation**

**रिषाद्सम्:-property of rishada (rusting)**

**वरुणां:-oxygen**
Varuna is the substance that is acceptanble to all. It is the element that every living being needs to live. This verse say that varuna has property ofrishadha, i.e., it eats away or rusts all the base metals, it burns all the bones, etc; and physiologically purifies the blood by oxidizing it, and thereby keeping the frame alive it is by these properties that varuna is in general distinguished; but it is especially characterized here as rishadha.Undoubtedly, It is oxygen.

**मित्रम:- hydrogen**
Now it is well known that hydrogen is the lightest gas and and it has strongest affinity with oxygen. Here, Mitra is associated with varuna(oxygen). Mitra, for instance, occurs as synonymous with udana, in many parts of Vedas, udana is well characterized by its lightness or by its power to lift up.

**पूतदक्षं:- pure energy**
Puta is pure, free impurities. Daksha means energy. Puta-daksham is a substance, pure, possessed of kinetic energy. Who that is acquainted with the kinetic theory of gases, cannot see in puta-daksha the properties of a gas highly heated?

Comment: i've heard of maitra-varuna being very closely associated deities. Maybe this is what they meant ? holy moly scriptures ! Can you link the source ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/www.vedicpress.com/composition-of-water/%3famp @ram

Comment: What is the word for water here?

Answer (score 0):

According to the renowned Vedic Scholar Sri Mukkur Lakshmi Narasimhacharyar Swamy, Atharva Veda has a mantra describing water as the mixture of two airs ("dvau vAyau militvA") in the proportion described as "prANam ekam anyam dve" (one part of prANa-vAyu and two parts of another).

prANa-vAyu or the life-air is interpreted to be Oxygen and the 'other' can be inferred to be Hydrogen.

I could not trace this mantra in the extant Atharva Veda so far.

Source - Kurai Onrum Illai book by Sri Mukkur Swamy